# Cannot add a contact related to account without Direct checkbox

Tags: opportunity, account, contact, related-list, checkbox

I want to add a contact, related to an account, as the contact of an opportunity, but I can only select the related contacts that have the checkbox “Direct” active. This checkbox I cannot see, edit or setup. Could you please suggest me a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that  there was a lookup filter on Opportunity object. It had to be removed.